# Javascript handling data in a gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have from date and to date. I am getting valid date on submit button in gridview.

I have kept validations on date fields but  if valid dates are given the data is shown, then again without refreshing the page if I give the wrong dates the validations are shown but the last data is also visible.

How to handle that situation?

```
function Validate() {


    var FromDate = document.getElementById('<%=frmDate.ClientID %>').value;
    var ToDate = document.getElementById('<%=toDate.ClientID %>').value;

    if (FromDate == "") {

        alert("Select From date");
        return false;
    }

    if (ToDate == "") {

        alert("Select To Date");
        return false;
    }


    if (Date.parse(FromDate) > Date.parse(ToDate)) {
        alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!")
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Data showed on previous valid request should be disabled on next request to page with invalid request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the gridview if validation fails

```
$('table[id$=gridViewId]').hide();
```

else if all validations pass then show it

```
$('table[id$=gridViewId]').show();


function Validate() {


    var FromDate = document.getElementById('<%=frmDate.ClientID %>').value;
    var ToDate = document.getElementById('<%=toDate.ClientID %>').value;

    if (FromDate == "") {
        $('table[id$=gridViewId]').hide();
        alert("Select From date");
        return false;
    }

    if (ToDate == "") {
        $('table[id$=gridViewId]').hide();
        alert("Select To Date");
        return false;
    }


    if (Date.parse(FromDate) > Date.parse(ToDate)) {
        $('table[id$=gridViewId]').hide();
        alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!")
        return false;

    }

    //Validations passed hence show the gridview
    $('table[id$=gridViewId]').show();
}
```